# How can I mirror a polygon using Python?

Tags: python, shapely

I have a set of images over which polygons are drawn. I have the points of those polygons and I draw these using Shapely and check whether certain points from an eye tracker fall into the polygons.

Now, some of those images are mirrored but I do not have the coordinates of the polygons drawn in them. How can I flip the polygons horizontally? Is there a way to do this with Shapely?

Comment: I recommend you to use a more general tagg such as 'python' sothat your question will reach more people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to reflect a polygon with respect to a vertical axis, i.e., to flip them horizontally, one option would be to use the `scale` transformation (using negative unit scaling factor) provided by `shapely.affinity` or to use a custom transformation:

```
from shapely.affinity import scale
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def reflection(x0):
    return lambda x, y: (2*x0 - x, y)

P = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [0, 1]])
print(P)
#POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 1 2, 0 1, 0 0))

Q1 = scale(P, xfact = -1, origin = (1, 0))
Q2 = transform(reflection(1), P)

print(Q1)
#POLYGON ((2 0, 1 1, 1 2, 2 1, 2 0))
print(Q2)
#POLYGON ((2 0, 1 1, 1 2, 2 1, 2 0))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jancso my pleasure! :)

Comment: Flip by `y-axis`: `scale(P, yfact = -1, origin = (1, 0))`

Answer (score 8):

by multiplying `[[1,0], [0,-1]]`, You can get the vertically flipped shape. 
(I tested this on jupyter notebook)

```
pts = np.array([[153, 347],
                [161, 323],
                [179, 305],
                [195, 315],
                [184, 331],
                [177, 357]])
display(Polygon(pts))
display(Polygon(pts.dot([[1,0],[0,-1]])))
```

[image: jupyter_notebook_result]

And If you multiply `[[-1,0],[0,1]]`, you will get horizontally flipped shape.

Refer [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Examples_of_linear_transformation_matrices) to understand why this works.